# Unable to write uni-code charecters inside a File, values are being trimmed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application, and i wrote the following code to create some txt files , as follow:-

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(serverpath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".txt"))
{   
    var tt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resourceinfo.operation.Details.PASSWORD);
    fs.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resourceinfo.operation.Details.PASSWORD), 0, mainresourceinfo.operation.Details.PASSWORD.Length);
}
```

Now in my case if the `resourceinfo.operation.Details.PASSWORD` == `£¬£¬`  it will be saved inside the txt file as `£¬` so can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you write the complete byte array.

[UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is an encoding that encodes characters in 1, 2, 3 of 4 bytes. If you encode a string to a byte array you can't no longer use the original string length as an indicator for the number of bytes you have to write

```
 // get the bytes in some encoding
 var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(resourceinfo.operation.Details.PASSWORD);
 // write all the bytes, using the array length and not the string lenght
 fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Do note that you could use a [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3aadshsx(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap your filestream and have the `StreamWriter` handle the encoding for you.